# How to create form and form array details post in angular 4 with Controller and Business Layer?

Tags: c#, angular4-forms

I'm facing an exception in the business layer at line:

```
PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository.Save();
```

I'm not able to save my data to database. This is my code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(PeriodicConsumption value) 
{ 
    int result = 1;
    PeriodicConsumption objPeriodicConsumption = new PeriodicConsumption();
    using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        try
        {
            uof.StartTransaction();
            PeriodiConsumptionRepository.Insert(value);
            PeriodiConsumptionRepository.Save();

            int IPeriodicConsumptionId = PeriodiConsumptionRepository.GetAllData().ToList().Last().Id;

            foreach (PeriodicConsumptionItem objPeriodicConsumptionItem in value.PeriodicConsumptionItems)
            {
                PeriodicConsumptionItem ObjPeriodicConsumptionItem = new PeriodicConsumptionItem();
                ObjPeriodicConsumptionItem.Consumption = objPeriodicConsumptionItem.Consumption;
                ObjPeriodicConsumptionItem.Cost = objPeriodicConsumptionItem.Cost;
                ObjPeriodicConsumptionItem.InventoryItemId = objPeriodicConsumptionItem.InventoryItemId;
                ObjPeriodicConsumptionItem.PeriodicConsumptionId = IPeriodicConsumptionId;
                PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository.Insert(ObjPeriodicConsumptionItem);
                PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository.Save();
                result = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            uof.RollBackTransaction();
            ErrorLog.ErrorLogging(ex);
            result = 0;
        }
        uof.CommitTransaction();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In controller:  public HttpResponseMessage Post(PeriodicConsumption value)
        {
            int result = 1;
            PeriodicConsumption objPeriodicConsumption = new PeriodicConsumption();
            result = PeriodicConsumptionBusines.Create(PeriodiConsumptionRepository, PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository, AccountTransactionTypeRepository, WarehouseComsumptionRepository, CostItemRepository, value);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }

Comment: Help friends,  i am suck here. if you need more information i will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show use the code of PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository.Save();?

Comment: Please, look the previous code from business layer and controller too.above.

Comment: getting error message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.PeriodicConsumptionItems_dbo.WarehouseConsumptions_PeriodicConsumptionId_WarehouseConsumptionId\". The conflict occurred in database

Comment: looks that your PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository.Save(); is try to safe the data in database but something is wrong with your FK. To solve this we need more information.

Comment: what type of data do you need ? i will provide.

Comment: PeriodicConsumptionItemRepository.Save(); + the db schema for the table which you want to save. And the data which occure the error

Comment: problem solved.